# Proper use of generics with collection instance factory

Tags: java, generics, factory, apache-commons

I'm trying to do the following thing using Apache Commons Collections v4:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesPerNumber = 
        MapUtils.lazyMap(
            new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(), 
            FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(ArrayList.class));

namesPerNumber.get(1).add("Mickey");
```

But I get the following compiler error at the lazyMap call:

> The method lazyMap(Map<K,V>, Factory<? extends V>) in the type MapUtils is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<Integer,List<String&t;>, Factory<ArrayList>)

Is there any proper way to use the factory for generating lists in a map? I tried also this:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesPerNumber = 
            MapUtils.lazyMap(
                new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(), 
                FactoryUtils.<List<String>instantiateFactory(ArrayList.class));
```

But then I get this error at the instantiateFactory call:

> The parameterized method <List<String>>instantiateFactory(Class<List<String>>) of type FactoryUtils is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ArrayList>)

The only working solution I found is the following, but I find it ugly:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesPerNumber3 = 
            MapUtils.lazyMap(
                new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(), 
                new Factory<List<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<String> create() {
                        return new ArrayList<String>();
                    }
                });
```

Any help appreciated.

Signed,
lostingenerics

Comment: You could try forcing the type with a cast, like this: `MapUtils.lazyMap(
            new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(), 
            (Factory<List<String>>)FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(ArrayList.class))`

Comment: Your first example compiles fine with Java8.

Comment: @tsolakp: not with my Java 8…

Comment: You are right, it does not compile but Eclipse was not showing any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to type erasure, class literals support only reifiable types or raw types, so `ArrayList.class` represents the raw type `ArrayList`, not the intended `ArrayList<String>`.

One way to solve this, is by using one unchecked operation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") Class<ArrayList<String>> type = (Class)ArrayList.class;

Map<Integer, List<String>> namesPerNumber = 
    MapUtils.lazyMap(
        new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(), 
        FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(type));
```

Note that the effect of `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is intentionally limited to the single unchecked operation here.

Or you use

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesPerNumber = 
    MapUtils.lazyMap(
        new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(), 
        FactoryUtils.prototypeFactory(new ArrayList<String>()));
```

instead.

If you are using Java 8, the best option is

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> namesPerNumber = 
    MapUtils.lazyMap(new HashMap<>(), () -> new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Thanks! Java8 seems cool, but unfortunately not available at the current project (yet). I like the most the prototypeFactory solution. My only consideration here is the performance of clone vs new. But internet seems to think that for empty collections it is comparable. Would you agree?

Comment: That is unlikely to become performance relevant and yes, I think the differences are negligible.